# How do I make the current folder path to work for my command

Tags: python, blender

I'm new to Python and really want this command to work so I have been looking around on google but I still can't find any solution. I'm trying to make a script that deletes a folder inside the folder my Blender game are inside so i have been trying out those commands:

```
import shutil
from bge import logic
path = bge.logic.expandPath("//")

shutil.rmtree.path+("/killme")  # remove dir and all contains
```

The Folder i want to delete is called "killme" and I know you can just do: `shutil.rmtree(Path)`

but I want the path to start at the folder that the game is in and not the full C:/programs/blabla/blabla/test/killme path.

Happy if someone could explain.

Comment: Solved, thanks alot! ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using shutil.rmtree command in wrong way. You may use the following.

`shutil.rmtree(path+"/killme")`

Look at the reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

Syntax: shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)

Assuming that your current project directory is 'test'. Then, your code will look like the follwing:

```
import shutil
from bge import logic
path = os.getcwd() # C:/programs/blabla/blabla/test/
shutil.rmtree(path+"/killme")  # remove dir and all contains
```

> NOTE: It will fail if the files are read only in the folder.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set a base path like

```
basePath = "/bla_bla/"
```

and then append the path and use something like:

```
shutil.rmtree(basePath+yourGamePath)
```

If you are executing the python as a standalone script that is inside the desired folder, you can do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env_python
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
shutil.rmtree(cwd)
```

Hope my answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could do is use the **os** library.

Then with the os.path function you can list all the directories and filenames and hence can delete/modify the required folders while extractring the name of folders in the same way you want.

```
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk("issues"):
        for name in dirnames:
           for filename in files:
              *what you want*
```

Comment: Thanks for all the support guys, I have tried almost everything you have said but sadly I keep getting this error `Python script failed, look in the console for now...` what I have tried is:
`import shutil
from bge import logic
basePath = "/test/"
shutil.rmtree(basePath+"/killme")` and `import os
cwd = os.getcwd("/test/")
shutil.rmtree(cwd)` and import shutil
from bge import logic
path = os.getcwd("/test/") # C:/programs/blabla/blabla/test/
shutil.rmtree(path+"/killme")` but the error keeps apearing. The console doesn't say.

Comment: Oh I just checked my console and on every error it tells "No module named "bge"." So I think the script is not the problem, it is the (import bge) that doesn't work. Gonna check that up! ^-^

Comment: Yeah, then you should probably install that module first. Let us know if the error persists.